# Mocking a module function and it's return

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I hope this is a straightforward answer, but I've been stuck trying to sort this out. I'm looking to mock out the following scenario. I previously had something like this that worked:

```py
# path/to/some/module.py

class MyClass:
    # None of the methods or init should ever run in a test
    def __init__():
        pass

    def do_thing():
        pass

def get_my_class():
    return MyClass()
```

```py
# path/to/some/other/module.py

from path.to.some.module import get_my_class()

def do_something()
    get_my_class().do_thing()
    return 'something'
```

```py
# test/path/to/some/other/module.py

from path.to.some.other.module import 

def test_do_something():
    with patch("path.to.some.module.MyClass") as mock:
        assert do_something() = 'something'
        mock().do_thing.assert_called_once()
```

So that was fine - the asserts worked, and the init and class methods were not called. But then I needed to move around some logic, and now I am unable to sort out how to get this to work from a mocking standpoint. The code itself works, I am just unable to get my mocks in a row. See below for the latest structure:

```py
# path/to/some/module.py

class MyClass:
    # None of the methods or init should ever run in a test
    def __init__():
        pass

    def do_thing():
        pass


class MyClassSingleton:
    _my_class = None


def get_my_class():
    if MyClassSingleton._my_class is None:
        MyClassSingleton._my_class = MyClass()
    return MyClassSingleton._my_class
```

```py
# path/to/some/other/module.py

from path.to.some.module import get_my_class()

def do_something()
    get_my_class().do_thing()
    return 'something'
```

I tried updating my test to be something like:

```py
with patch("path.to.some.module.MyClassSingleton._my_class") as mock:
```

but this leads to the `MyClass.__init__` code running, which is no bueno.

My goal is for everything to work more or less as before from a mocking standpoint, ideally with as simple a setup/boilerplate as possible since I need to apply these changes to hundreds of tests. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "need to apply these changes to hundreds of tests" - I highly recommend using pytest fixtures for this purpose.

Comment: That's a good call out. I imagine I can just return the mocked object from within a context manager in the fixture and that should work? I'll give it a shot once I have this working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the easiest answer was to create a patch for the singleton, but also mock out the `_client` reference as well. So I made a fixture like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_client() -> MagicMock:
    """
    Provide a mocked client via singleton that does not initialize
    """
    mock_provider = MagicMock()

    with patch("path.to.some.module.MyClassSingleton", mock_provider):
        yield mock_provider._client

def test_do_something(my_client):
    assert do_something() = 'something'
    mock.do_thing.assert_called_once()
```

It is possible I could have mocked out `get_my_class`, but as I was moving towards a fixture-based approach, this proved to be less desirable, as I would import `get_my_class` into various modules, which meant the patch target reference to `get_my_class` would have to change, which would mean parameterizing fixtures which I didn't want to chase down.

Because the provider/singleton class was only accessed via `get_my_class`, by mocking the provider I was able to have a single fixture that would work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`patch('path.to.some.module.MyClassSingleton._my_class')` is already an instance of MyClass so, the problem is calling `assert_called_once` in `mock().do_thing`, you should've been calling it in `mock.do_thing`.

```py
def test_do_something():
    with patch('path.to.some.module.MyClassSingleton._my_class') as mock:
        assert do_something() == 'something'
        mock.do_thing.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot at this. The problem is the init method on MyClass is run under the new construction, which fails in the test context (it fails before it ever makes to to the mock.do_thing assertion). I need to fully circumvent the init, which is what was happening previously.